# Problemas ao autenticar usuários de tipos diferentes - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-auth

No meu sistema eu tenho dois modelos, o de Usuário (User) e o de Cliente (Client), cada tipo de usuário vai ter suas roles definidas. Exemplo:

Usuário:

- Administrador
- Funcionário

Cliente:

- Gestor
- Contador
- Recursos Humanos

No meu arquivo `auth.php` está assim:

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
     */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'user',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
     */

    'guards' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'client' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'clients',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
     */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Client::class,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
     */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'clients' => [
            'provider' => 'clients',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Cliente:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Client extends Authenticatable
{    
    protected $guard_name = "client";
    protected $table = 'clients';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'cpf', 'function', 'area', 'email', 'phone', 'access', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function userable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Usuário:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Auth;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;
    use Impersonate;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'cpf', 'function', 'photo', 'access', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\User', 'userable');
    }
}
```

OBS: Os dois modelos tem praticamente os mesmos campos e eu poderia usar herança, mas pra evitar confusão, optei por separa-los. Creio que isso não atrapalhe na autenticação, mas caso eu estiver errado, me avise.

O problema é que se eu tentar fazer o login com algum 'Cliente' eu não consigo, não é demonstrado nenhuma mensagem de erro, o login só não acontece.

**Solução:**

Ao que parece, o Laravel não suporta múltiplos tipos de usuário 'nativamente' na hora da autenticação. Foi necessário adicionar um 'bundle' pra ajudar nessa autenticação de múltiplos tipos de usuários. Utilizei este bundle:
[Hesto/multi-auth](https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth)

Comment: Na classe Client acho que falta use Auth;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lembrando que você deve trocar o driver de autenticação de acordo com o Tipo do usuário, você pode fazer através de um Middleware. Exemplo:

```
config([   
          'auth.defaults.guard' => 'user',
          'auth.defaults.passwords' => 'users'
        ]);
```